# LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle with multiple provider

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm using LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle with Api-Platform. I have multiple provider like this :

```
providers:
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email

    app_candidat_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Candidat
            property: email
            
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    candidat:
        pattern: ^/candidat/authentication_token
        anonymous: true
        lazy: true
        stateless: true
        provider: app_candidat_provider
        json_login:
            check_path: /candidat/authentication_token
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    main:
        anonymous: true
        lazy: true
        stateless: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        json_login:
            check_path: /authentication_token
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

It's working when I'm getting the token with candidat firewall 'candidat/authentication_token' but when I'm using the token with authorization header, it's loading the user with main firewall instead of candidat.

How does the bundle know which firewall to use only with a token ?

How to deal with multiple providers ?

Thanks by advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony uses only one firewall per request and it's the first matched with the pattern. So in your case it's using candidat firewall for ^/candidat/authentication_token urls, and with others request does not matches candidat pattern, they will use "main".